# what is the concept of using function as variable in event binding?

Tags: angular, event-binding

I am trying to look into `ControlValueAccessor`, I have noticed some function `_onChange` as variable, bound to `input` event. Please let me know why `_onChange` function is not being called on `input` event, what is significance of such event binding.

template:

```
  <input #passwordInput
         type="password"
         [id]="id"
         class="form-control"
         [disabled]="disabled"
         (input)="_onChange($event.target.value)" 
         (blur)="_onTouched()"
  >
```

component:

```
 _onChange = (value: any) => {
    console.log(`At _onChange`);  

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql_dummy, the function _OnChange is a variable that you asign in your registerOnChange

```
registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this._onChange = fn;
}
```

So, each time you call to this function Angutar notificate to the app that the control has changed. You can not "override" this function. If when you change your input want to do "something more" you use, e.g.

```
<input #passwordInput  (input)="OnInput($event.target.value)" ..>

//and
OnInput(value:any)
{
   //..make something more...
   console.log(value)
   //finally you call to the function
   this._onChange(value)
}
```

**Update** Brief explain

Imagine you has a customForm component `<myComponent [formControl]="control">` or `<myComponent [(ngModel)]="variable">`. How Angular know that sould change the value of the formControl or the variable?: When you, in your custom component, call to the function _onChange.

You can e.g. write some like

```
  <input #passwordInput
         type="password"
         [id]="id"
         class="form-control"
         [disabled]="disabled"
         (blur)="_onChange($event.target.value);_onTouched()"
  >
```

And in your app you see that only change the value of the formControl or the variable when you "blur" the input. This is the reason if we has an input we generally use the event `(input)` -it's better that use the event (keyup). We are saying to Angular that each change in the input, send the value to the app.

Another example, imagine that your custom component is in the way

```
<button>option 1</button>
<button>option 2</button>
<button>option 3</button>
```

Yes, I know that is a very fool custom component this three buttons, it's only an e.g.

We can call to the function _onChange in the (click) of each button with a different value

```
<button (click)="_onChange(1)">option 1</button>
<button (click)="_onChange(2)">option 2</button>
<button (click)="_onChange(3)">option 3</button>
```

Comment: but what is the significance of `(input)="_onChange($event.target.value)" `,  Also I was following video "Angular Forms – Kara Erickson – AngularConnect 2017", at 15:05 it is mentioned such function should be callable on `input`.

Comment: I updated the answer. The idea is that each change in input is "propagated" using the function _onChange